# Jmeter Write data into Csv and read the same in another thread group

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

My requirement is to Create users in one thread group and save the users in row format in csv.

Use another thread group to read the csv and run it in loop for all users in csv.

But ReadData2 thread group is not reading the data when ran sequentially.
and is working when ran independently.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file needs to **be present** when "ReadData2" Thread Group starts so make sure that the file is there and contains i.e. a header line or something like this.

The file can be created in i.e. [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) or create it beforehand and append new entries programmatically as needed.

With regards to using Beanshell: it's a some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating.